# Getting application context from a CommandLinerRunner

Tags: spring-boot

How can we get access to ApplicationContext from a CommandLineRunner class. Is there a better newer way than using ApplicationContextAware

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Autowiring would work, either as a field

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

or a method

```
@Autowired
public void context(ApplicationContext context) { this.context = context; }
```

Same as `ApplicationContextAware` really.

It's a smell in any case - maybe if you think about your use case you will find a way to do it without the context?

Comment: Well I am dynamically creating spring integration application contexts for file:inbound-channel-adapters and the idea here is to pass the parent application context to child contexts to allow them to use beans defined in parent application contexts.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public CommandLineRunner listAllBeans(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      
     return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            System.out.println("doing listAllBeans");
            for(String beanName : allBeanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }
        }
     };
  }
```